# Why Computed Setters don't update the View?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I have two buttons in the view. You can select the *list* layout or the *group* layout. The state has to be saved in the localstorage or cookie.

```
// Pug Syntax
#app
  span.button(
    :class="{'active': layout === 'list'}",
    @click="change('liste')"
    ) List

  span.button(
    :class="{'active': layout === 'group'}",
    @click="change('group')"
    ) Group
```

Here is the vue.js code:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  computed: {
    layout: {
      get() {
        // Get from cookie or localstorage
        return // Returned from cookie
      },
      set(newValue) {
        // Save to cookie or localstorage
        return newValue
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    change(value)
    {
      this.layout = value
    }
  }
});
```

If i click on the buttons, the cookie has the new data, but the button don't get the *.active* class. Am I using the *Computed Properties* right?

Comment: You're not returning anything in the computed's `get`...

Comment: And you're not setting anything in the computed's `set` :)

Comment: It's an example code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Computeds only update when reactive values are updated. Cookie values are not reactive, so the `get` doesn't know when there's a new value. You'll need to use a real `data` item for `layout` and maintain it by copying data to and from the cookie or localStorage or whatever.